# C# CLR stored procedure with table-valued parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, clr, table-valued-parameters

I have SQL Server stored procedure with a table-valued parameter

```
CREATE TYPE T_WORD AS TABLE
(
   SWC_Index INT IDENTITY,
   SWC_Value VARCHAR(MAX)
)

CREATE PROCEDURE SP_LOG 
    @i_msg             VARCHAR(4000) ,      
    @i_word        T_WORD READONLY   
AS
BEGIN
   SET  IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS  ON

   declare @i int
   SET @i = 1

   while (@i <=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @i_word))
   begin
       INSERT INTO LG_REPORT
       values(@i_msg,(select SWC_Value from @i_word where SWC_Index =  @i))
   end

   IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
      COMMIT
END
```

And I need to write a C# CLR wrapper that simply executes this procedure in a new connection.

C# code looks like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

namespace SQLCLR
{
    public partial class StoredProcedures
    {
        [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
        public static void exec_SP_LOG(Object i_msg, Object i_word)
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
            {
                SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand();                
                SqlParameter i_msgParam = new SqlParameter("@i_msg", SqlDbType.VarChar);                
                SqlParameter i_wordParam = new SqlParameter("@i_word", SqlDbType.Structured);
                i_wordParam.TypeName = "T_WORD";

                i_msgParam.Value = i_msg;                
                i_wordParam.Value = i_word;

                Command.Parameters.Add(i_msgParam);                
                Command.Parameters.Add(i_wordParam);

                Command.CommandText = "exec SP_LOG @i_msg, @i_word";
                Command.Connection = connection;

                connection.Open();

                Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After adding the dll to SQL Server and creating procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[exec_SP_LOG]         
    @i_msg             sql_variant ,
    @i_word        sql_variant
AS 
EXTERNAL NAME [SQLCLR].[SQLCLR.StoredProcedures].[exec_SP_LOG]
GO
```

I try to execute this function

```
declare @typ1 T_WORD
insert into @typ1(SWC_Value) values('djhgfj')
insert into @typ1(SWC_Value) values('dfhdf')
exec exec_SP_LOG 't1', @typ1
```

However I get the following error

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure exec_SP_LOG, Line 0
>   Operand type clash: T_WORD is incompatible with sql_variant

It looks like something is wrong with datatype of table-valued parameter in C#.

The question is how to pass table-valued parameters properly in C# and therefore what is the proper datatype to be used for calling this extended procedure from SQL Server.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look at the definition for the input parameter in the generated XML after building the .DLL; it'll have `sqlvariant` instead of `T_WORD` - replace it, and bingo.

Comment: Side note: [CREATE PROCEDURE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx): "Avoid the use of the **sp_** prefix when naming procedures. This prefix is used by SQL Server to designate system procedures. Using the prefix can cause application code to break if there is a system procedure with the same name."

Comment: Thanks for your response, however, when I change datatype for this column in xml file and then rebuild the project in order to generate the new dll, this xml file gets rewritten again with datatypes declared in .cs Please advise how to rebuild the project after manual change of xml file avoiding it being rewritten again?

Comment: @MaxVernon regarding the advice to "it'll have `sqlvariant` instead of `T_WORD` - replace it, and bingo": that won't work. TVPs cannot be passed to SQLCLR objects. Please see my answer for additional details.

Comment: I don't know about "won't work"... I've done it and it has worked.

Comment: @MaxVernon You are saying that you can pass in a TVP into a SQLCLR proc and/or function?

Answer (score 4):

There are quite a few things that need to be addressed in this code:

1. The overall design seems to fit less into a Microsoft SQL Server world and more into an RDBMS like PostgreSQL, or even Oracle (and maybe others?). It looks like you are trying to make SQL Server work like one of these other systems (or at least expect that it does), but it doesn't. I am saying this because you should spend some time reading about the various datatypes, transaction handling, and set-based vs iterative/cursor-based approaches.
2. > how to pass table-valued parameters properly in C#

   Well, you do have `i_wordParam` set correctly to `SqlDbType.Structured`. And you have `i_wordParam.TypeName` set correctly to `T_WORD`. Just FYI, setting the `TypeName` is only required for ad hoc queries, not when calling stored procedures via `CommandType.StoredProcedure`.

   So if you had either a `DataTable`, `SqlDataReader`, or method that returned `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>` in the C# code already, then you could pass that along to `SP_LOG` with how you currently have that interaction set up.
3. > what is the proper datatype to be used for calling this extended procedure from SQL Server.

   The issue (the main issue, at least) is that you cannot pass TVPs to SQLCLR objects. As stated in the MSDN page for [CREATE PROCEDURE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx):

   > - Table-valued or **cursor** data types cannot be used as parameters.

   TVPs are not Data Types: they are Table Types. User-Defined Table Types are used to create Table Variables. So while you do have the .NET `Object` Type mapping to the T-SQL `SQL_VARIANT` datatype correct, a `SQL_VARIANT` cannot be assigned a Table Variable. This is why you got the **Operand type clash: T_WORD is incompatible with sql_variant** error.
4. As @Damien_The_Unbeliever already pointed out in a comment on the question, you really shouldn't use the `sp_` prefix for user objects as that is reserved for the system and causes the `master` database to be checked first for that object.
5. Unless you have a very explicit reason for doing so, I wouldn't use `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON`. You should start a transaction explicitly via `BEGIN TRAN`. If a transaction was already started prior to this proc being called (i.e. `@@TRANCOUNT` would be > 0 at the beginning of this proc) then the `COMMIT` at the end would cause an error as the value of `@@TRANCOUNT` would be less at the end of the proc than at the beginning.

   If the reason for using Implicit Transactions is to not start a transaction if `@i_word` is empty, you can just exit the proc by adding the following at the beginning:

   ```sql
   IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @i_word))
   BEGIN
     RETURN;
   END;
   ```
6. You don't have any error checking or `ROLLBACK` logic. You should be using something along the lines of:

   ```sql
   BEGIN TRY

     BEGIN TRAN;

     ... one or more SQL Statements

     COMMIT;

   END TRY
   BEGIN CATCH

     ROLLBACK;

     ;THROW; -- introduced in SQL Server 2012

     ---- Remove "THROW" and use the following if on SQL Server 2008
     -- DECLARE @ErrMessage NVARCHAR(4000) = ERROR_MESSAGE();
     -- RAISERROR(@ErrMessage, 16, 1);
     -- RETURN;

   END CATCH;
   ```
7. Regarding `while (@i <=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @i_word))`

   If you needed a WHILE loop (you don't; more on that in a moment) then you don't want to do the `COUNT(*)` in the loop as it will be evaluated each time.
8. Regarding the structure of the WHILE loop:

   You don't ever increment `@i`, hence you have an infinite loop. If you needed the WHILE loop, it would require `SET @i += 1;` if using SQL Server 2008 or newer, or `SET @i = @i + 1;` if using SQL Server 2005.
9. There is no need for a WHILE loop in the first place. Table-Valued Parameters are just that: tables (albeit Table Variables, but still). Hence, they can be JOINed, etc. The following is a much more efficient approach:

   ```sql
   INSERT INTO LG_REPORT
     SELECT @i_msg, tmp.SWC_Value
     FROM   @i_word;
   ```
10. When inserting, you really should specify the field names. Hence `INSERT INTO LG_REPORT (column1, column2)` instead of just `INSERT INTO LG_REPORT`. Not specifying the field names allows for the situation where you add a field to `LG_REPORT` and forget to update this `INSERT` and it fails. Or maybe you don't have the fields in the right order. Stuff like that.
11. While it won't cause errors, you (everyone, really) *should* get in the habit of ending each query with a semi-colon.